# Get old Xcode Object Library style from Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, xcode10

is it possible to get the old Xcode 9 object library style at the bottom right in the right tab. Im using Xcode 10 beta 6[image]

Comment: whoever that came up with the idea of removing the object library from being docked, needs to be sacked from Apple...

Comment: yea :( i hate that

Comment: The product manage of this change should definitely be fired for this decision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to use this shortcut ⇧+option+⌘+L then it stays consistent until u close it

Comment: Thank you! This is just bad UX, it's unbelievable!

Comment: OK, I see. So when you click on `View` from the menu and then press the `Option` key, you will see a new action called `Open Library` instead of `Show Library`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't.

In [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/103777) Apple forum post you can find the Release Note of the change.

To open the library with a shortcut use ⇧+⌘+M