# How to dock Objects Library in Xcode 10

Tags: xcode10

After I upgraded to Xcode 10. I noticed that the Objects Library is floating instead of docked at right bottom corner.
And a new button added at the top tools bar.
How can I dock it to the corner as Xcode 9 did.
[image]

Comment: Do you want the Xcode 9 behavior with the Library at the bottom right of the window, or are you looking for a way to keep the Library window open all the time?

Comment: I just want the Library at the bottom right same as Xcode 9

Comment: Take a look at the following question: [Go to old Xcode Object Library style from Xcode 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028048/go-to-old-xcode-object-library-style-from-xcode-10)

Comment: Thanks. That’s ok. Just need to be used to it. LoL

Answer (score 20):

As of now, you cannot. But you can make your life easier if you click **Objects library button** while holding the **Option** key. Object library will become a resizable window and it will stay there until you close it.

Comment: ack xD I hate that haha

Comment: Damn it, did Apple fire their UX people?

Comment: I think poor Tim Cook just cant bring himself to throw chairs at people (possibly Jonny Ive lol) over UI struff like Steve Jobs did.

Answer (score 3):

UPD for Xcode 11:

**Ctrl** + **Shift** + **L** to open Library.

Then you click on this tiny button that says 'hide details'.

[image]

It resizes the library window. Then you put it in the bottom corner or wherever you like.

[image]

Now if you drag some item from the library window, it will disappear. Oups...

> The trick is to press **Option** key when you drag something **for the first (!) time**.

It will keep the window docked in the same place until it's closed.

**P.S.**

Next time you open library use **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **Option** + **L**. Window will appear in the same place. And you don't need to press **Option** key on the first drag.

Comment: ugh, but it's still not actually docked like it used to be