# How to fix the libraries menu(for storyboard) on window (Xcode 10)

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I just upgraded my Xcode version to Xcode 10.
But It is so uncomfortable to me when I tried to add an object to a view in storyboard.
Is there any way to fix this libraries in Xcode window? like before version?

+)For some people who having trouble with finding an storyboard object in Xcode 10, 
the View > Libraries menu, or the ⇧⌘L/⇧⌘M keyboard shortcut is the way to see Libraries!

Comment: This is a duplicate. Please see solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52858601/1048520

Answer (score -2):

In xcode 10 It is easy , You have to press **command+shift+L** and the object library window will pop up . There you can search and hit return or drag the object to storyboard . 
Actually this change is made so the attribute inspector can have more space than before .

Comment: As I said I know how to see the libraries menu in Xcode10...I  want to know hot to fix it in Xcode window like before versions